# Different response model examples based on HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, swashbuckle

**What I have:**

I have an API where all non-success responses return an "IApiException"

```
public class ApiException : Exception, IApiException
{
    public ExceptionType Type { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode Status { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; } = new List<Error>();

    public ApiException(ExceptionType type, Reason reason, string message, HttpStatusCode httpStatus)
    {
        Type = type;
        Errors.Add(new Error { Message = message, Reason = reason.ToString() });
        Status = httpStatus;
        Code = httpStatus.ToString();
    }
}
```

If I set the example in swashbuckle through an ISchemaFilter
it will put the same example on all model examples, so a 401 will return the same example as a 429.

## What I want:

I want to be able to return different examples based on the status code.

## Wha I've tried:

I tried creating an IOperationsFilter looking for the response keys and then setting either the response schema example or the response examples.
But it's is not displaying the models, at all.

```
public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
{

    foreach (var response in operation.responses)
    {

        if (response.Key == "401")
        {

            response.Value.description = "Error";                  
            response.Value.schema.example = new
            {
                Type = ExceptionType.Error.ToString(),
                Errors = new {Message = "Unauthorized", Reason = Reason.Unauthorized},
                Status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                Code = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

[image]